# Return all column headings based on cell value

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet (well 5 of them) with a list of 20 teaching topics. Students rate each topic as Red, Amber, Green at the end of each lesson. Ultimately I want to mail merge a summary of these in an easy to read format for students, so they get:
Topics I have rated as red are:
Topic 1, Topic 2 etc

To use if formulas in word is way too long as there are 3 options for 100 topics.

I would therefore like to combine all the column headings (topic names) into a cell at the end of the row and just mail merge this to word. (it may not be the prettiest). As I need to share this spread sheet with others it can not use macros. 
I want to combine the column headings based on a criteria (whether each cell has R, A or G on it).

e.g.

```
Name Topic 1  Topic 2   Topic 3  Topic4  SummaryRed        SummaryA  SummaryG

Fred R        G         A        R       (Topic 1,Topic 2) (Topic3)  (Topic2)
```

Sorry, that hasnt formatted very well, I have seperated columns with commas.

Any help appreciated
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

This should work for R's.  For other letters, just change the "r" below for the corresponding letter.

```
=CONCATENATE((IF(F10="r",F9,"")), ", ",(IF(G10="r",G9,"")), ", ",(IF(H10="r",H9,"")), ",         ",(IF(I10="r",I9,"")))
```

Comment: Thats great, thank you, dead simple too, now I just have to extend it for another 20 columns and 9 spreadsheets!